# Merging a dataframe by specific column for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

How do you merge the data so that you always merge to the longest column.

Currently my code is:

```
csvs = lsit of data frames

df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='LEVELS',how="left"), csvs)
df_final = df_final.fillna('')
```

Which produces this:

[OUTPUT 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fl5h.png)

However this only works if the dataframe with the longest column is on the left, if it was on the right it produces this:

[OUTPUT 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZDhq.png)

How do I ensure it always goes in the direction towards the longest column

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried if statement according to the length of the rows?
for instance

```
row1=df1.shape[0]
row2=df2.shape[0]  
if row1>row2:
xxxxxxx
else:
xxxx
```